# Quickest way to write database backed web services

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, database, web-services, rest

I know you can easily expose your database through web services with whichever framework/language you like, but is there a really quick tool for this task in *programming space*? (ie, without relying on a particular database vendor tool, like Oracle's ones)

Some background. I have a bunch of tables in my design files and all I want is to make the data available through REST services (with a little bit of authentication/authorization). I don't want to manage the database by hand - ie with `CREATE TABLE`, `ALTER TABLE` - neither writing *migration* files: the runtime will do this the best it can. Also, the runtime will generate the JSON/XML in some automagic way by exploiting the request

All programming languages will suit - Java, Groovy, Scala, Python, Ruby, you name it - and so do all frameworks/runtimes.

I think this is a fairly common problem, but I'd take hours to solve it - so I think I'm missing something and I hope there's a way to achieve this in *minutes* or maybe *seconds* :) Indeed, these seems repetitive tasks that can be automated

**EDIT**
I know there are Grails, Lift, Rails, Django, Code Igniter and so on :) I can search Google myself, really! I want to know if there is a pre built software stack to do this tasks with almost no configuration and no time! In essence I'm looking for a way to speed up the phase between the design and the integration with other software - since we are talking of web services, not human interfaces - so I need opinions by people who actually know the tool they are talking about and can state "*with MightyFramework you get this task in 30 minutes and 20 lines of code*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you have a look at [Grails](http://www.grails.org) framework. It provides out of box support for returning json/xml. Also, exposing RESTful web service is a breeze.

Comment: what about the ORM part? I think Grails people call it GORM. How do you manage physical tables?

Comment: Grails uses Hibernate for ORM and generates the physical tables based on entities. Since you already have physical tables, you can have a look at http://grag.sourceforge.net/ - which lets you generate grails entities based on existing database tables.

Comment: I don't actually have the tables. I have only the design :)

Comment: In that case, you will have to create the domain classes and generate controllers/views yourself. The time required to create these will depend on the size and complexity of your db design.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be DBMS agnostic then you'll probably end up using an ORM tool, like Hibernate, possibly using hibernate-tools to generate classes from your tables. Once you have these classes, you'd use JAXB to serialize them to json and xml and [RestEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy) to serve that RESTfully.

Comment: This tools require the DB to be already set up? Also, I think Hibernate is just the ORM part, what about the REST one?

Comment: well you said you already *have* a bunch of tables you want to expose.

Comment: I'll edit my question to be clearer. Indeed, I only have the design files (well, I can create the tables in 30seconds or so...). Anyway, you suggested a plethora of component (you'll also need to deal with http) that will need to be wired together, and it'll actually take time... My primary objective is speed things up

Comment: If you knew all these technologies, then it'd be fast :) and it's much faster to learn them than to develop everything yourself anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/). I haven't used it a lot myself, but when I tried it out, pretty much everything I did was shockingly simple to do with this framework. It seemed very simplistic but still very flexible and powerful. I'd presume there are a bunch of caveats that might show up in the long run if you want to do something a little more advanced, but I definitely recommend checking it out.

One of the highlights is fully automatic database management - all you have to do to persist an object instance is to `save()` it. If a table for such objects does not already exist, it is created on the fly. Loading objects from database is equally simple.

Comment: This is very interesting. What about the REST part and the overall configuration?

Comment: At least the basic configuration, to get it up and running, was very simple. As for REST... As I said, I haven't worked much with Django. But I do know from my little experiment that creating plugins for it is extremely easy, so I'd guess if it isn't included by default there's probably one or more good plugins for that.